# VB.NET Filesystemwatcher

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET, I have written a code, within a button click event, which should watch a folder for arrival of files. Upon arrival of a file, it should 'do something'

Code snippet below:

```
'start of code
File System Watcher

    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Changed Then
    'Do Something

    If e.ChangeType = IO.WatcherChangeTypes.Created Then 
    'Do Something

'end of code
```

Now, when I click the button, and after clicking the button, files are added to the folder, then the code works fine, by 'doing something'

However, if files are pre-existant in the folder before the button click; and then if I click the button, then the code does NOT 'do something.

Please suggest changes to the code snippet above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nature of a `FileSystemWatcher` it watches for changes to a given directory.

> Use FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a specified directory. You can watch for changes in files and subdirectories of the specified directory. You can create a component to watch files on a local computer, a network drive, or a remote computer.

Link: [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Maybe you could run some code at the start of the click to process files that are present first, then the watcher can do it's thing.

Comment: thanks ! that worked. i added at the start of click, and it worked. thanks again

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: @vicki : If this solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on its left.